# How to add 'all' CASE when group by CASES in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a query like this:

```
select
case when  sp.provider='prv1' and    sp.status_code = 404 then 'failed'
     when  sp.provider='prv1' and    sp.status_code = 200 then 'success'
     when  time_taken is null or sp.status_code in (503) or sp.status_code is null then  'unavailable' 
     else 'other'
    end as result,
    count(*)
from services_serviceprofile sp
where 
service_type = 'type1' and
sp.provider = 'prv1' and 
sp.start_time >= '2022-08-22 00:00'
group by 
  case when  sp.provider='prv1' and    sp.status_code = 404 then 'failed'
         when  sp.provider='prv1' and    sp.status_code = 200 then 'success'
         when  time_taken is null or      sp.status_code = 503  or sp.status_code is null then  'unavailable' 
         else 'other'
    end 
order by count(*) desc;
```

Which gives the result:
[image: query result]

How can I add a row for 'all' requests in CASES? If we add a `when sp.provider='prv1'` with no more detailed condition then all cases become one 'all' case because and other cases are ignored.

Comment: you don't, not in the `CASE` itself. You must compute it separately and append it to the result using UNION, or you can let whatever tools use those data to compute the total itself

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: @jarlh It is postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that inside the `CASE`, as it behaves like a series of IF.

You need to compute the total separately and append it using `UNION` or delegate the total calculation to whatever tool uses those data.

```
WITH RequestStats
AS (
     SELECT
           CASE 
               WHEN sp.provider = 'prv1' AND sp.status_code = 404 THEN 'failed'
               WHEN sp.provider = 'prv1' AND sp.status_code = 200 THEN 'success'
               WHEN time_taken IS NULL OR sp.status_code IN (503) OR sp.status_code IS NULL THEN 'unavailable'
               ELSE 'other'
               END AS Result
           ,count(*) AS RequestCount
     FROM services_serviceprofile sp
     WHERE
          service_type = 'type1'
          AND sp.provider = 'prv1'
          AND sp.start_time >= '2022-08-22 00:00'
)

SELECT 
      Result
     ,RequestCount
FROM RequestStats

UNION ALL

SELECT 
     'All' AS Result
     ,SUM(RequestCount) AS RequestCount
FROM RequestStats
```

Comment: Your answer is awesome but without having `group by` section i receive this error:
`column "sp.provider" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`. Can you guide me to fix this?

Comment: I solved the issue by adding `group by` to the `RequestStats`.  The `UNION` solution was so insightful. Tnx bro

Comment: Glad to help. do you mind marking the answer also as accepted/solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on SQL Server 2008 or later version, you can use the ROLLUP() GROUP BY function for add last row total:

```
select results = ISNULL(result, 'All'), Counts = sum(Counts)  from (
select
case when  sp.provider='prv1' and    sp.status_code = 404 then 'failed'
     when  sp.provider='prv1' and    sp.status_code = 200 then 'success'
     when  time_taken is null or sp.status_code in (503) or sp.status_code is null then  'unavailable' 
     else 'other'
    end as result,
    count(*) as Counts
from services_serviceprofile sp
where 
service_type = 'type1' and
sp.provider = 'prv1' and 
sp.start_time >= '2022-08-22 00:00'
group by 
  case when  sp.provider='prv1' and    sp.status_code = 404 then 'failed'
         when  sp.provider='prv1' and    sp.status_code = 200 then 'success'
         when  time_taken is null or      sp.status_code = 503  or sp.status_code is null then  'unavailable' 
         else 'other'
    end 
) as Final
```